# How do I write an "or" logical operator on Prometheus or Grafana

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I need to write a query that use any of the different jobs I define.

```
{job="traefik" OR job="cadvisor" OR job="prometheus"}
```

Is it possible to write logical binary operators?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Prometheus has an `or` logical binary operator, but what you're asking about here is vector selectors.

You can use a regex for this `{job=~"traefik|cadvisor|prometheus"}`, however that you want to do this is a smell.

Comment: Okey really thanks!! it works for me, I don't think it is a smell, its only for the templating variable (not for grafana graphics)

Comment: why would an or operation be a smell? seems like something that would be very practical

Comment: I also see no reason why it would be a code smell, some elaboration on that point would be good.

Comment: also works for prefixes: `".*traefik |.*cadvisor"` or even better: `*.(traefik|prometheus)`