# Query using multiples operator OR

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I need to write a query that use any of the different tag I define, because the historian database supports only this type of where condition.
{tag="pressure" OR tag="level" OR tag="prometheus"} Is it possible to write logical binary operators?

I don´t know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43134956/10305444

Our solutions would be

```
that_query{tag=~"pressure|level|prometheus"}
```